# How to transfer at Dubai between Terminals 2 and 3 with luggage?

Tags: transit, luggage, dxb

I'm arriving in Dubai at Terminal 2 with flydubai and my flight with Emirates leaves from Terminal 3. As they are separate bookings, I realise I have to collect my luggage and clear Customs and Passport Control etc.

How do I transfer from Terminal 2 to Terminal 3 with luggage?

Is a taxi the best way, or is there a bus?

Answer (score 0):

Check with airline.

> Terminal 2 (F Gates)
>
> If you are connecting to or from F Gates (located across the tarmac), **your airline will tell you what to do**. Services include free shuttle buses, Marhaba service and public transport.

http://www.dubaiairports.ae/before-you-fly/procedures/flight-connections